# How to retrieve data from webservice with pagination using pentaho data-integration tool?

Tags: data-integration, pentaho-spoon

I am attempting to use the rest client to query a webservice for data. The flow is as follows:

1. POST request with the query that returns a cursor Id (Get Initial Cursor)
2. GET request with the cursor ID to retrieve the first batch of 5000 rows

   - Along with the data, the response contains the next and previous cursor id (Extract Cursor Id, Get data with cursor)
3. Use the next cursor from the request in step 2 to get more data and possibly another next cursor.
4. If next cursor is missing from the response, no more data is available.

What is the best way to implement a looping construct to keep retrieving data till 'next cursor' is unavailable?

Below is the diagram of my transformation:

[image: Transformation Diagram]